# Sharp and Crisp GUI in Ubuntu?

Tags: unity, gui

I have recently installed Ubuntu with the hopes of doing software development in a Linux environment.

However, coming from a Windows 7 environment, I can't help but notice how the default Ubuntu GUI (Unity) feels so unsharp, uncrisp, unresponsive, bloated, taking up too much space, etc.

For example, in Windows 7, the fonts are small but sharp and crisp, and the windows, forms and controls take up just the right amount of space. Using Ubuntu Unity, instead it feels as if the desktop shrunk in size and everything feels so cluttered.

What can I do to make my Ubuntu experience feel less cramped, and make it feel more sharp, crisp and responsive, at least to what we're accustomed to in Windows?

Answer (score 1):

Try the following to remove your existing setup and replace it with another desktop environment

```
Ctrl+Alt+F6
```

This switches to a full tty scripting terminal, without a GUI.  You can safely make changes to your GUI and desktop from here without restarting your computer.

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge ubuntu-desktop
```

This uninstalls, and deletes all the files for, the Ubuntu desktop package, including unity, x, display settings, etc.

```
sudo apt-get install kubuntu-desktop
```

Installs kubuntu desktop, a lightweight and powerful integrated desktop environment.  Incredible features when paired with koffice office suite.

```
sudo apt-get install lubuntu-desktop
```

Installs lubuntu desktop, another gnome based lightweight desktop.  Best suited for low end hardware.

**IMPORTANT EDIT:**

I was just thinking about your question, when it dawned on me that your Ubuntu install might not be using your video card, hence the lack of detail you're suffering from.

Check this before anything.  Find this info by opening system settings, then System Details.  A few lines on the first tab describe the devices used by the operating system, including the currently used graphics processor.

If it doesn't match the name of your current GPU, then do some searches about installing that brand of graphics driver on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

This can be a religious thing, but I just never loved Unity... Gnome-Shell is a completely different experience and its worth a try since your starting out with Ubuntu... This will tell you how to install: http://www.webupd8.org/2013/03/gnome-38-beta-available-in-ppa-for.html

After installing, you will want to check out the large library of great extensions out there for Gnome Shell: https://extensions.gnome.org/